# Compute the bias of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{z_i}{\sigma_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, estimation, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I found the maximum likelihood estimator of $x$. Now, how to compute the bias of:
$$
\hat{x}_{ML} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{z_i}{\sigma_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}
$$

Where $\hat{x}_{ML}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $x$, the relationship of $z$ and $x$ is: $z_i=x+v_i$ being the error $v_i$ a Gaussian noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma_i^2$. I got stuck here:

$$
Bias(\hat{x}_{ML})=|x-\mathbb{E}\left(\hat{x}_{ML}\right)|=\left|x-\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{z_i}{\sigma_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}\right)\right|
$$

Now, I do not know how to get inside the expectation, becasue the expectation of the quotient is not the quotient of expectations....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{z_i}{\sigma_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}\right)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\mathbb{E}\{z_i\}}{\sigma_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}$$

Comment: And the denominator?? Do you leave it without the expectation?

Comment: The denominator is deterministic and contains no random variable.

Comment: Oh wait, I guess its becasue it is not random...  SO TRUE

Comment: That's right. You got it!